# How to initialize the \numquestions value for the first run in exam class

Tags: exam, auxiliary-files

I try to put the following `\TheNumQuestions` newcommand using the counter of questions in exam class, in this simple program:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\newcommand\TheNumQuestions{\ifthenelse{\numquestions=1}{1 question}{\numquestions\ questions}}

\begin{document}
This exam contains \TheNumQuestions
\begin{questions}
\question A first question
\question A second question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

but I have, for the first run, the following error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\unhbox
l.6 ^^IThis exam contains \TheNumQuestions
```

After, for the second compilation, all remains good, and it compiles well.

When I look at the auxilliary file, I found the following information `\gdef\exam@numquestions{2}`, which gives the suited result, for the second compilation. How can I insert a similar command in the auxilliary file, for use in the first compilation, and avoid this error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that, during the first run, `\numquestions` expands to `\mbox{\normalfont \bf ??}`, which is not a number, and you are applying a numerical test to it.

Instead of comparing `\numequations` to `1` as a number, you can test wheter `\numquestions` expands to `1` using `\equal` (also from the ifthen package).

Here is the result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\newcommand\TheNumQuestions{\ifthenelse{\equal{\numquestions}{1}}{1 question}{\numquestions\ questions}}

\begin{document}
This exam contains \TheNumQuestions
\begin{questions}
\question A first question
\question A second question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]